# Root web folder points to /var/www

Tags: apache2

Not sure if this is the right place for this, but I have been running an Owncloud instance on my home server. I originally did it through apt-get, and ran it in the default folder (/var/www).

I later migrated it to a different drive so that I could separate the operating system and Owncloud in case I ever upgrade my system.

Today, I ran an update, not thinking about it, and Owncloud updated, but rather than update at the new location, it downloaded and reinstalled OC to the default folder. That would be fine, but for some reason, when I try to go localhost/owncloud, it sends me to /var/www despite the Apache settings having been changed to the new folder.

I checked all the apache configurations, and they all point to the same place. I can't seem to find any reason why OC would be doing this.

Did the update create a symlink that I can't find or something? If so, how would I find them?

Comment: I would assume that there is a owncloud.conf(or similar) that gets included into /etc/apache2/conf/ (with a symlink). Another something: maybe the 'default' site got installed in sites-enabled?

Comment: I couldn't find the problem, so I decided to make my own symlink. It's not the most elegant fix in the world, but it did the job.

Comment: Care to provide what you did as an answer and upvote/accept it?